# How to resolve a Name Error with Input and Strings

Tags: python

I have a problem with input,  I include the code and error. The problem is very basic but I can't resolve it.

The code is:

```
    name = input("What is your name? ")
    print("Hello ", name)

    line 2, in <module>
        name = input("What is your name? ")
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    NameError: name 'luca' is not defined
```

Comment: please add the full code

Comment: Is it Python2 or 3?

Comment: If it is python2, use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Comment: `NameError` means you are referencing a variable that has not been declared yet. In your case its `luca`.

Comment: I used Python 3. My input accept only number, not text. I need that accept text.

Comment: If you ran the code you presented and got the error you presented then you're running it with Python 2. Period.

Comment: That code can't produce that error.

Answer (score 0):

For python2 you should use:

```py
name = raw_input("What is your name? ")
```

But may i suggest using python3? Using python3 will not complain about your example.